# Generic validation for request param and request body in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, validation

How to write or configure generic validation annotation or class for request param and request body instead of validating one by one

The below example we are validating one by one in the method itself. Instead of that how to validate generic way which we will use for all the methods and class rather than validating each method

```
    @PostMapping(value="/agreements/{agreement-number}/payments", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> initiatePayment(@Valid @RequestBody PaymentInitiateModel paymentInitiateModel,
            @RequestHeader(value = "orgCode", required = true) @Valid @NotNull(message = "Mandatory Field Missing") @Size(min = 3, max = 10, message = "Min/Max Length Validation Failed")  String orgCode,
            @RequestHeader(value = "apiName", required = true) @Valid @NotNull(message = "Mandatory Field Missing") @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Min/Max Length Validation Failed")  String apiName,
            @RequestHeader(value = "uniqueRefNo", required = true) @Valid @NotNull(message = "Mandatory Field Missing") @Size(min = 3, max = 15, message = "Min/Max Length Validation Failed")  String uniqueRefNo,
            @RequestHeader(value = "requestTime", required = true) @ValidDate @NotNull(message = "Mandatory Field Missing") String requestTime,
            @RequestHeader(value = "status", required = true) @Valid @NotNull(message = "Mandatory Field Missing") @Size(min = 1, max = 10, message = "Min/Max Length Validation Failed")  String status,
            @RequestHeader(value = "remarks", required = true) @Valid @NotNull(message = "Mandatory Field Missing") @Size(min = 3, max = 10, message = "Min/Max Length Validation Failed")  String remarks,
            @PathVariable("agreement-number") String agreementNumber)
    {
```

Comment: Precisely, why would you really want to make that change? The code, as it currently is, gives plenty of readability, in the sense that you can see the necessary attributes for each field, which won't happen if everything is grouped together as you propose.

Answer (score 0):

You can create data classes and give validation constraints in those classes. It will look something like the following.

```
public class ExampleRequest {

    @NotBlank(message = "app.user.full.name.invalid")
    @Size(max = 128, message = "invalid.field.size.128")
    private String fullName;

    @NotBlank(message = "invalid.format.phone.number")
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11, message = "invalid.field.size.128")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @NotBlank(message = "app.user.mail.invalid")
    @Size(max = 128, message = "invalid.field.size.128")
    private String mail;

    @NotBlank(message = "app.user.password.invalid")
    @Size(max = 128, message = "invalid.field.size.128")
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "app.user.password.confirm.invalid")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 32, message = "password.character.count.invalid")
    private String passwordConfirm;

    @NotNull(message = "app.user.role.names.null")
    private Set<String> roleNames;

    private Long companyId = -1L;
```

}

Then use it with `@Valid` annotation and it would work.

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> exampleMethod(@RequestBody @Valid ExampleRequest exampleRequest) {
    // ...
}
```